# How to Select Element That Does Not have Specific Class

Tags: javascript, html, class

I'm wondering how to select an element that does not have a specific class using JavaScript, not jQuery.

For example, I have this list:

```
<ul id="tasks">
  <li class="completed selected">One Task</li>
  <li>Two Task</li>
</ul>
```

and I select the completed task by:

```
var completeTask = document.querySelector("li.completed.selected");
```

But then I'm not sure how to select the list item that does not have those classes.

Answer (score 289, accepted):

This selects the second `LI` element.

```
document.querySelector("li:not([class])")
```

or

```
document.querySelector("li:not(.completed):not(.selected)")
```

**Example:**

```js
// select li which doesn't have a 'class' attribute...
console.log(document.querySelector("li:not([class])"))

// select li which doesn't have a '.completed' and a '.selected' class...
console.log(document.querySelector("li:not(.completed):not(.selected)"))
```

```html
 <ul id="tasks">
    <li class="completed selected">One Task</li>
    <li>Two Task</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 27):

To select the `<li>` that has not `completed` nor `selected` class:

```
document.querySelector("li:not(.completed):not(.selected)");
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8djF/

Comment: How to [do the reverse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39822557/2284570) : that is, select all elements that have both`completed`and`selected`class ?

Comment: @user2284570 just write both classes without whitespaces: `li.completed.selected` -> this will match all those `li` elements that have `completed` AND `selected` class

Answer (score 13):

You can try the `:not()` selector

```
var completeTask = document.querySelector("li:not(.completed):not(.selected)");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UM3j5/

Answer (score 11):

The `:not(*selector*)` selector also accepts commas (so does `querySelectorAll()`) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#syntax:

```js
let plainElements = document.querySelectorAll( ':not( .completed, .in-progress ) ');
plainElements.forEach( ( item ) => { item.style.color = 'red'; } );
```

```css
li { color: green; }
```

```html
<ul id="tasks">
  <li class="completed selected">Task 1</li>
  <li>Task 2</li>
  <li class="in-progress">Task 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[wf-body=details] input:not(.switch):not(.btn)').forEach(function(e){
    // do whatever you want. with 'e' as element :P
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting an array of the parent's children instead:

```
var completeTask = document.querySelector("#tasks").childNodes;
```

Then loop/search them as necessary.