# JavaScript - how to delete elements that do not have a specific class?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to delete all elements that do not have the class `'stay'`

For example:

```
<div class="stay">Stay</div> 
<div class="stay">Stay</div> 
<div class="go">Go</div> 
<div class="element">Stay</div> 
<div class="Sel">classy</div>
```

I would like some javascript that would delete the elements that do not have the class `stay` and `Sel`, without having to list the classes `go` and `element` 

I have used:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('#parent :not(.stay)');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i])
}
```

from the first answer, but am unsure of how to keep the class `'Sel'`.

Also, I DO NOT want any Jquery.

Comment: This question and its answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975881/how-to-select-element-that-does-not-have-specific-class

Comment: just show what code you tried, and facing errors, so we will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing such an operation should need to target a particular parent element, else it could also remove elements like html/body etc.

So assuming you have a parent node, you can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) in conjunction with [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="stay">Stay</div>
    <div class="stay">Stay</div>
    <div class="go">Go</div>
    <div class="element">element</div>
</div>
```

then

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('#parent :not(.stay)');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].parentNode.removeChild(els[i])
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8gb9dpsm/)