# How to recursively select all children under an element Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need a function that recursively selects all child elements but wont select elements (and those elements children) if they have the "foo" attribute.

```
<section>
  <div>
   <span foo>
    <input>
   </span>
  </div>
  <p>
    <img>
  </p>
</section>
//should return [section, div, p, img]
```

I need raw Javascript please

edit:
I tried something like this:

```
$tag.querySelectorAll(":not([foo])")
```

but querySelectorAll(":not([foo])") will still return the children of the unselected element.

Comment: Im stuck with the not selecting children part, I've tried using querySelectorAll(":not([foo])") but that will still return the elements under the foo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) with the `:not` modifier here, together with the `[attr]` selector:

```
var nonFooElements = parentElement.querySelectorAll("*:not([foo])");
```

Be aware that this sort of call will be moderately expensive because the selector doesn't begin with an id or a classname, so don't do huge amounts of it.

I adapted this answer from this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21975970/5009210

Comment: This doesn't select FooElements, but it does select the children of the foo elements. That is the part I'm stuck at.