# Getting divs by classes with querySelector() and exclude other class

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to simply get all of the first divs while exlcuding the second divs:

```
<div class="_5pcr userContentWrapper">
<div class="_5pcr userContentWrapper _4nef">
```

I searched and fout of that the querySelector function should be doing the job. However I tried it with multiple inputs, but all of those result in an empty list. If I use the DOM function getElementsByClass it works but then of course I got all divs, also the second ones that I don't want.
Here are the querySelector function calls I tried:

```
listOfPosterName = document.querySelectorAll('div._5pcr userContentWrapper:not(._4nef)');
listOfPosterName = document.querySelectorAll('DIV._5pcr userContentWrapper');
listOfPosterName = document.querySelectorAll('_5pcr userContentWrapper:not(_4nef)');
listOfPosterName = document.querySelectorAll('DIV.userContentWrapper:not(_4nef)');
```

I have even tried to just get the same result as with "getElementsByClass('_5pcr userContentWrapper')" with this:

```
listOfPosterName = document.querySelectorAll('_5pcr userContentWrapper');
```

That also did not work. I thought it's a problem because of the space between the classes, but I tested it also with a single class.

I really appreciate help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975881/how-to-select-element-that-does-not-have-specific-class

Comment: *getElementsByClassName* just looks for elements with matching classes based on a space separated list, it can't exclude matches based on some other criterion (e.g. the `:not` pseudo–class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is just putting too much spaces where unnecessary:

```
  listOfPosterName = document.querySelectorAll('._5pcr.userContentWrapper:not(._4nef)');
```

Answer (score 5):

You are not writing the selectors correctly.

When you want to select an element having multiple classes you would do:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class1.class2.class3');
```

When you leave a `space` character in a selector - it becomes what is called a `descendant` selector. Example:

```
<div class="class1">
  <p class="class2"></p>
</div>
```

In this case, `class2` could be selected with a `descendant` selector:

```
document.querySelector('.class1 .class2');
```

Your fixed example could look like so:

```
<div class="_5pcr userContentWrapper">
<div class="_5pcr userContentWrapper _4nef">

document.querySelectorAll('._5pcr.userContentWrapper:not(._4nef)');
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector()` works just fine, but you have to pass it the selector properly. Multiple classes should be concatenated together, not space separated like in the HTML.

```js
document.querySelector("._5pcr.userContentWrapper").classList.add("selected");
```

```css
.selected { background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="_5pcr userContentWrapper">Me</div>
<div class="_5pcr userContentWrapper _4nef">Not Me</div>
```