# Why doesn't my className selector return an element?

Tags: javascript, html

With this code, I get into the class "v1Nh3 kIKUG _bz0w" , so basically `first_pic.className` equals "v1Nh3 kIKUG _bz0w". I get the same result by using the line which I have commented out. But now how can I use this to get the href link (I marked it blue in the picture below) and print it out with `window.alert`?

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("SCxLW  o64aR ")[0].children;
var x_in = x[0].children;
var x_in_in = x_in[3].children;
//window.alert(document.querySelector("main.SCxLW.o64aR article div div div div").className);
var first_pic = x_in_in[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0];
window.alert(first_pic.href);
```

[image]

Comment: try this  `document.querySelector('article.ySN3v .kIUG a').href;`

Comment: @Sarout Is there a way to do this slightly different? Because the names are not always same for me,

Comment: well, you can do it without classes `document.querySelector('main div div article div div div div a').href` ...

Comment: If the class names change can you guarantee the structure of the document won't change too?

Comment: this is generated code from a framework (like react, vue, ...) The elements are not rendered on page load. Best solution is the modify the component which will render this html

Comment: @Sarout Works thanks!

If someone has a working solution that is not using qerySelector but something else, please feel free to share it because I'm interested to see it! :)

Comment: no, I can't guarantee but when you say the class names change I get it **only** class names changes... anyway if I find another way I'll write it here directly

Comment: @kathelk does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975881/how-to-select-element-that-does-not-have-specific-class) helps?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. `className` refers to a single class, not the entire value of the class attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you cannot rely on the changing classes, you should focus on the tag names.

I would try this:

```
let link = document.querySelector("main article:nth-child(1) a")
console.log(link.href)
```

EDIT

Another thing to try would be to focus on something unique and "stable"... like the `tabindex` attribute:

```
let link = document.querySelector("[tabindex='0']")
console.log(link.href)
```

Another EDIT *(answer to OP comment under his question)*

> If someone has a working solution that is not using querySelector but something else...

If the link is the very first of the `article`, this would work:

```
let article = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0]
let link = article.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]
console.log(link.href)
```

Comment: this will work I think but the comment says that the structure of the document may 'change'

Comment: Internet may go down too... And the Russians may invade Ukraine. Now we just can work with what we have.

Comment: hahaha, yeah and the resurrection may come, how OP would select his element??

Comment: @Sarout sorry I forgot to mention this details, only few class names keep changing but the structure remains same (so always same amount of divs, children etc.)

Comment: I know this, but I'm talking about the one who said *what if the structure of the document changed*

Comment: If the classes always change AND the document structure also changes... There is nothing to be done.